# c++ reading characters in from a file char by char using only char arrays[]

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am working on an assignment for my c++ class, and I am pretty close to solving my problem. At this point, I am getting output that is ALMOST what I was expecting, so I suspect that I may be misunderstanding a core concept of this problem. The part of my assignment I am working on now is to get a file name from the user, read in that file, and then display that file while replacing key characters. For example, :!, will be replaced with '\n' to make a new line. I am only allowed to use iostream and fstream, and all text must be handled with char arrays[]. In my current output, I am getting an extra space on the third line, and I do not understand how it is getting there. Because of this, I think I may have the logic wrong in my head, and was wondering if any more experienced programmers could explain where I am going wrong. Am I going in the right direction?

here is the text file I am using as practice: 1.txt

```
Type, type, type away :!
compile.
Run.
Hip hip hooray! :! No errors today! :!
```

This is the expected output of the same file: 1.txt

```
Type, type, type away
compile. Run. Hip hip hooray! 
No errors today!
```

this is the output that I am getting

```
Type, type, type away
compile. Run. Hip hip hooray! 
 No errors today! <<-------- extra space at the beginning!
```

I will paste my code below, feel free to critique it in any way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 1024 // this is the maximum allowed number of char in a file.
                 // is it a bad idea to define it as a constant?

int main()
{
    char fileName[256];
    char data[MAX];
    int readFile(char fileName[],char data[]);
    void display(char data[], int counter);
    fstream file;

    cout << "File Name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    int counter = readFile(fileName, data);
    display(data, counter);

    return 0;
}

int readFile(char fileName[], char data[])
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open(fileName);

    int count = 0;
    while(file.get(data[count]) && count < MAX)
    {
        count++;
    }
    file.close();
    return count;
}

void display(char data[], int counter)
{
    char formatText(char data[], int count);
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        if(data[i] == '\n') // I added this if statment in because the newline
        {                   // from the file was getting read, AND the :! was
            data[i] = '\0'; // becoming \n, printing out TWO new lines!
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        formatText(data, i);

        if(data[i] != ':') // All tokens have a : before, So i dont want to 
            cout << data[i]; // print out the :'s.
    }
}

char formatText(char data[], int count)
{
    if(data[count] == ':')
    {
        switch(data[count + 1]) // these are the three tokens I have been given,
        {                       // but it has to be expandable for more later.
            case '!': data[count + 1] = '\n';
                break;
            case '<': data[count + 1] = '\"';
                break;
            case '>': data[count + 1] = '\"';
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

I'm sorry if this has been answered in another post, I was unable to find (or possibly understand) the answer to my question. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You should use `constexpr` instead of `#define`. It is less error-prone.

Comment: It looks to me like the space you are complaining about should be there. It is in your input file (a space after the :!) hence unless your requirements were also to strip leading whitespace, I think your current output is correct.

Comment: If the expected output is to condense/drop leading and trailing whitespace and extra whitepace between words, you'll best solve this with two flags: 1) one flag records that you've seen a space so that when you encounter a letter you first output a space, _except_ when you are translating your special newline code or when: 2) another flag records that you've seen the first non-space character on the current line -- if that is not set, you never output any leading space.

Comment: my teacher has a program that runs my version against hers with the same text file. In her version, it doesn't have that extra space, even though there is a space after the :! in the text file! hmm.... would it be possible for me to read in all characters ignoring white space, and then add them in correctly afterward in the display function? My teacher's program seems to be ignoring all white spaces except the ones that exist between words. God, I wish I could just use strings.

Comment: @paddy If I am only reading one char at a time, how can I know if the space I am reading is the first one in the line?

Comment: You know exactly when a new line starts, don't you?  That's what this whole program does.

Comment: @paddy Maybe I could check to see if the space before (i-1) is a \n, because that would mean it is the first space in the line, correct?

Comment: @paddy yeah, sorry :) I wasn't thinking. I thought there might be a built-in function or something. my bad. Let me try that out and I'll come back to the results.

Comment: If there's something about my description you don't understand, feel free to ask for clarification.  Maybe read it a few times.  Note the distinction: the `seen_space` flag is set when you find a space and cleared when you find a non-space.  The `seen_nonspace` flag is cleared when you start a new line and set when you encounter a non-space.  Also notice I'm drawing conclusions about the output requirements, since you are a bit vague on the specific details of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Type, type, type away :!
compile.
Run.
Hip hip hooray! :! No errors. today! :!
```

ok. the first thing you do in formatting is remove all the newlines '\n' in the character array and that leaves you with

```
Type, type, type away :!compile.Run.Hip hip hooray! :! No errors today! :!
```

then you replace all the !'s preceded by :'s with '\n' but if you notice that in this state all your :!'s have a non whitespace character in the next index position save one.

```
 :! No errors
```

and that's your error, because it then replaces your sequence as `\n  No errors`

changing your input data to

```
Type, type, type away :!
compile.
Run.
Hip hip hooray! :!No errors today! :!
```

fixes that extra space problem.